# Binding multiple event handlers after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I am loading some content in to an html div using the `.load()` method.

```
$("#cards").load("/cards/?offset="+offset);
```

the new content contains several `<a>` to which I would like to bind event handlers. For the first, I am using the `.on()` method:

```
$('body').on('click', '#excerpt-slide', function() { alert('Link 1 Clicked'); }
```

When I attempt to bind the second event handler to a different `<a>`, clicking the link does not trigger the anonymous function:

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-count', function() { alert('Link 2 Clicked'); }
```

Do I need to unbind `click` event handlers for them to work properly?

Please help.

Comment: are you sure you have an anchor with id **add-count**

Comment: we would need to see more of your code...there is no reason for it not to work if the element selector is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be missing an anchor which has an id of add-count. For your information you don't have to unbind the event. jQuery can handle multiple event for a element.

You are missing closing `)` in your code

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-count', function() { alert('Link 1 Clicked'); } ); 

$('body').on('click', '#add-count', function() { alert('Link 2 Clicked'); } );
```

[check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Ljg/)

That's all I can tell with the code and the details you have given